# Ubuntu 20.04 Raspberry Pi error "vc_sm_cma: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel" How to fix?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, modules, logfiles

I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 4. In my `/var/log/kern.log` file I am getting the following messages:

```
vc_sm_cma: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
vc_sm_cma: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
```

What do these mean and how can I fix it so my kernel isn't "tainted"?